# reverse bootstrap stacking at certain sizes.

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

To reverse the column display in bootstrap, you can use push and pull:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-6">Will show on right</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-pull-6">Will show on left</div>
```

Works great.

The catch is I want to reverse this but ONLY when they stack...so only on smaller screens. I don't want to change the visual left/right display but top/bottom.

So I have this:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">want to show below</div>
<div class="col-xs-12">want to show above</div>
```

I don't *think* you can do this with just bootstraps's CSS alone, or can you?

Answer (score 2):

### Pure CSS approaches

One method that ***may*** work in some circumstances would be to rotate both the wrapper element and the children elements `180` degrees.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/H7HjL/)

```
.wrapper,
.wrapper > div {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-180deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(-180deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(-180deg);
    transform:rotate(-180deg);
}
```

Support for this method can be [found here](http://caniuse.com/transforms2d).

---

As an alternative, you can change the [order of flexbox elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) too.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/apue3/)

```
.wrapper {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column-reverse;
}
```

Support for this method can be [found here](http://caniuse.com/flexbox) - add in other prefixes for more support.

If you want this CSS to take effect at a certain screen size, simply use media queries. Here are the media queries Bootstrap uses:

```
@media(max-width:767px){}
@media(min-width:768px){}
@media(min-width:992px){}
@media(min-width:1200px){}
```

---

### JavaScript alternatives

Since you're using Bootstrap, you're probably also using jQuery. Here is a little snippet that will reverse the order of the wrapper's children elements.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/3NeJ9/)

```
var wrapper = $('.wrapper');
wrapper.children().each(function(i,el){
    wrapper.prepend(el);
});
```

If you're not using jQuery, here is a pure JS approach to do the same thing.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/kL5W4/)

```
var wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper'),
    children = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper > div');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(children, function(el, i){
    wrapper.insertBefore(el, wrapper.firstChild);
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't that just turn my content upside down?

Comment: @DA. Did you look at the demo?

Comment: ah! I didn't! Cool (and weird!) that that does that. I need to play with this some.

Comment: OK, I had to think about that for a bit...we're flipping the WRAPPER and then we're flipping each of the divs within the wrapper. This is actually really clever!

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.

On small screens, bootstrap shows the elements in their natural order.

I'd try to do it the other way around (mobile first):
Order them in HTML the way you want them on small screens. Then change the order for bigger screens.